# Simulating a static variable for a function

Tags: python

**SOLUTION**: The error was that my function is actually a method.

I'm trying to use a decorator to simulate a variable for a function. Why do I get this error on the last line below? `global name 'onecmd' is not defined`

```
def static_var(varname, initial_value):
  def decorate(func):
        setattr(func, varname, initial_value)
        return func
  return decorate

@static_var("last", None)
def onecmd(self, line):
    if line == "lastcmd":
        line = onecmd.last
    else:
        onecmd.last = line
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code seems to expect to be able to access `onecmd` as a global, but this is a *method*. Functions defined at the module level are indeed reachable by their name (as they are stored as a global), but a class method is only stored in the class object.

You need to find the function object either via the class on which you defined this, or via the `self` attribute, following that back to the class and then the function:

```
@static_var("last", None)
def onecmd(self, line):
    onecmd = type(self).onecmd.im_func  # im_func is the wrapped function
    if line == "lastcmd":
        line = onecmd.last
    else:
        onecmd.last = line
```

Since you already have a class method, you'd be better off storing the variable on the *class* instead:

```
class Foo(object):
    last = None

    def onecmd(self, line):
        if line == "lastcmd":
            line = type(self).last
        else:
            type(onecmd).last = line
```

or even make this a class method instead:

```
class Foo(object):
    last = None

    @classmethod
    def onecmd(cls, line):
        if line == "lastcmd":
            line = cls.last
        else:
            cls.last = line
```